# Is there a text editor I can use on my Mac that can "ssh-sync" with my files on my remote server?

Tags: macos, text-editors

Every time I save a file on my Mac, I want it to auto-sync with the files on my remote server.

Are there any text editors that can do this?

Comment: It's called Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/

Comment: @Lukasa Some people (you know, those who value *privacy*) don't want [everyone having access to all their private data](http://news.cnet.com/8301-31921_3-20072755-281/dropbox-confirms-security-glitch-no-password-required/). Therefore, Dropbox isn't the answer for them.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Good point well made. You're absolutely right. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) is a web developer oriented source code editor that has integrated "site" management and assists in keeping the local and remote sites synchronized by highlighting all files with local changes and providing easy means to upload changed files.

It supports SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) for file transfer, and has some SSH capabilities (which I haven't used so far, though).

---

The TextMate 2 alpha was [just released](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/textmate-2-0-alpha/), and it has something similar to what you want: `rmate`. So if you log into SSH (not SFTP/SCP), you can run that script and edit the files locally using TextMate.

[image]

Comment: +1 Was going so suggest that as well (-> also worth taking a look at [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/), because its actually the base of Coda)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly what you want, but if you use [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) you can actually edit the file remotely by right clicking and selecting *Edit with...* and it will be uploaded automatically each time you save.

[image]

Consider combining it with a free text editor like [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), or if you want to spend some money its full-featured (but paid) counterpart [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/), or alternatively [TextMate](http://macromates.com/).

Cyberduck also has the option to synchronize a folder on demand (*Right click* → *Synchronize*) in case you need that.

Comment: Be careful with that! You're not keeping a backup of the file the way you would be if you downloaded the file and edited it locally. If your connection hangs and dies with the file half-uploaded, or if you accidentally save bad code, you've just put something up on the FTP server that you don't have a way to roll back from. I thought this feature was very convenient until the first time I shot my foot off with it...

Comment: Yes, that's a valid concern. Happened to me once and I lost quite a bit of work there.

Answer (score 1):

[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) for OS X is free, fast, and highly functional. It includes native capabilities to modify files via SFTP/SSH connections.

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)? That way when you've saved your file it should get ssh'ed across to the target machine. Here's a link that describes ssh http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but while [Agrajag9 suggested](https://superuser.com/a/368005/136319) TextWrangler, this has now been replaced by [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/).

I use BBEdit from macOS for editing files on remote servers via SSH all the time. You get nice browser for navigating the directory structure on the remote server and editing is seamless.

Also, with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com), you can go to extensions (press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or via the menu, “View” » “Extensions”), add “Remote - SSH” extension, and then you can use Visual Studio Code via SSH to a remote box. This isn’t (as of the time of writing this) 100% mature yet, but it works for me to ssh into a remote server. It even parsed the `~/.ssh/config` file and presented the server choices right in the UI (rather than BBEdit’s manual entry of this connection info).